# Docker failed to build .NET project, Copy Error

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

I have a C# project, I want to dockerize it. I have previously done containerized another c# project but this one looks like multi-layer project and the project path is like this
project directory

```
|-- Accounts.Data
|   |-- appsetings.Development.json
|   |-- appsetings.csproj
|   |-- Accounts.Data.csproj
|-- Accounts.Service
|   |-- Accounts.Service.csproj
|-- AccountsProject
|   |-- Projectfiles
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- AccountsProject.csproj
|   |-- appsettings.json
|-- Accounts.sln
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the .csproj files and restore NuGet packages
COPY Accounts.Data/*.csproj Accounts.Data/
COPY Accounts.Service/*.csproj Accounts.Service/
COPY AccountsProject/*.csproj AccountsProject/
RUN dotnet restore AccountsProject/AccountsProject.csproj

# Copy the entire project files and build the application
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AccountsProject"
RUN dotnet build AccountsProject.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

# Publish stage
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish AccountsProject.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Final stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app

# Copy published output from the publish stage
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# Set the entry point for the application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AccountsProject.dll"]
```

And this is the error I am getting after running `docker build --no-cache -t acc -f Dockerfile .`

```
[+] Building 1.1s (10/18)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                                                                                              0.9s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0                                                                                                                                                 0.9s
 => [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:b1ac02d48e170b007d2d2392119fa037e531f1ad93cf8433d911f402d00c743a                                                                                     0.0s
 => [final 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0@sha256:e855110445f4a1b48bb0d5b6de9f14cd2dd311b1daaf047bf0f3965cab3e4a25                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => transferring context: 26.57kB                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/9] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [final 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [build 3/9] COPY Accounts.Data/*.csproj Accounts.Data/                                                                                                                                            0.0s
------
 > [build 3/9] COPY Accounts.Data/*.csproj Accounts.Data/:
------
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount30709147/Accounts.Data: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The and files should be right next to sln and csproj file.

> Dockerfiledocker-compose.yaml

When you create a new project in Visual Studio and leave put project file inside the project folder this issue might occure. Make sure you have sln and csproj in the same folder. Also, the and docker-compose.yaml in the same folder too.

> Dockerfile